# Setting DNS servers on a VPN adapter in Windows 10 has no effect

Tags: windows-10, vpn, dns

I am connected to a VPN but Windows seem to completely ignore the VPN's DNS server - all names resolve to the same IP as they do when not connected to the VPN, including those that should resolve to a different IP.

I have tried manually setting the interface metric, changing the provider order... I must have tried every single advise I found that was vaguely related to my issue. No effect.

I noticed that when I run `$ nslookup <name>` the DNS request times out:

```
$ nslookup <name>
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.131.4.133

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

I have manually configured the DNS servers on the adapter to `46.101.81.247` and `8.8.8.8`. What I don't understand is why nslookup shows `Address:  10.131.4.133`.

ipconfig confirms that `10.131.4.133` is the first DNS on that interface:

```
PPP adapter My VPN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : My VPN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.7(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.131.4.133
                                       46.101.81.247
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1820A 802.11ac
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 30-52-CB-84-5D-FD
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::857c:1b6a:139:1e40%18(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.8(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 10 February 2017 23:12:22
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 11 February 2017 23:12:21
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 87053003
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-EF-9F-3E-30-52-CB-84-5D-FD
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

But IPV4 clearly shows only the two correct DNS servers:

[image]

```
$ route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...0a 00 27 00 00 0c ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #4
  3...0a 00 27 00 00 03 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #5
  4...32 52 cb 84 5d fd ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 55...........................City Pantry VPN
 18...30 52 cb 84 5d fd ......Dell Wireless 1820A 802.11ac
  5...30 52 cb 84 5d fe ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
 27...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 29...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 26...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
 28...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.8  13225
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link        10.10.10.7     36
       10.10.10.7  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.7    291
    46.101.81.247  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.8   8726
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.0.8   8981
      192.168.0.8  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.8   8981
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.8   8981
     192.168.33.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.33.1   4506
     192.168.33.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.33.1   4506
   192.168.33.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.33.1   4506
     192.168.99.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.99.1   4506
     192.168.99.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.99.1   4506
   192.168.99.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.99.1   4506
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.99.1   4506
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.33.1   4506
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.8   8981
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.10.10.7     36
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.99.1   4506
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.33.1   4506
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.8   8981
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.7    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  6    331 ::/0                     On-link
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  6    331 2001::/32                On-link
  6    331 2001:0:34ac:b067:8b3:794:d19a:ae08/128
                                    On-link
  3    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 18    306 fe80::/64                On-link
  6    331 fe80::/64                On-link
  6    331 fe80::8b3:794:d19a:ae08/128
                                    On-link
  3    281 fe80::1451:d2d3:6c7c:f5a8/128
                                    On-link
 18    306 fe80::857c:1b6a:139:1e40/128
                                    On-link
 12    281 fe80::c5f2:5798:ee23:573c/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  3    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 18    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
  6    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

What am I missing? Why is Windows ignoring the VPN's DNS server? And where does the `Address:  10.131.4.133` come from?